# VBA =COUNTIFS from different file, using variable for R1C1

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to turn this formula into VBA code:

```
=COUNTIFS('Report'!$J:$J,"=In Force")
```

However, I have acquired the column in the 'Report' file that I will be extracting the data from.  The column number it stores in variable `ColNum`. I need to ensure that it extracts data from the column variable that I have found, and from the 'Report' File.

Here is my code so far (I know it is not correct):

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(Report'!$I:$I,"=In Force")"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Use this UNTESTED formula. Where `FlName` and `Col` are variables.  `FlName`  is the name of the file without the Extension and `Col` is the Column Name.  
    `"=COUNTIFS('" & FlName & "'!$" & Col & ":$" & col & ",""=In Force"")"`

Comment: My apologies in advance for not testing it and posting a proper answer. But I was on my way out when I saw this question popping up.

Comment: No worries.  Unfortunately I couldn't get it working using my own variables.

Comment: Ahh I got it, it was just a problem with my other code.  Your's worked!

Comment: Awesome :) Btw, in a hurry, i wrote file name. It should be sheetname...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the number of the column (in the ColNum variable) that you wish to sum then you can use:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS('Report'!C" & ColNum & ":C" & ColNum & ",""=In Force"")"
```

If the name of the sheet is also in a variable, ReportName, then the formula is:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS('" & ReportName &"'!C" & ColNum & ":C" & ColNum & ",""=In Force"")"
```